# letters with diacritic marks disappearing in Evince Document Viewer

Tags: language-support, evince, okular

Letters with diacritic marks disappear in forms viewed with Evince Document viewer 3.18.2:

[image]

However, there is no problem typing letters with diacritic marks into the form:

[image]

I have the relevant Latvian language applied system wide:

[image]

The same problem applies to Okular.

What is wrong?
I work with Ubuntu 16.04